# An adjective for a person who is new to a certain field/activity

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for an adjective, a compound adjective or adjective phrase that would fill in the blanks below

> He is a [...] stamp collector.
>   *= He recently became a stamp collector.*
>
> She is a [...] mailwoman.
>   *= She recently became a mailwoman.*

The meaning I am looking for is that of a person being new to an activity, which is now performed by them regularly, in a positive sense.

Comment: Is the person a [**newbie**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/newbie) or are you looking for a more formal adjective? There might be a different adjective in each case, for example an inexperienced *worker* can be called a [**rookie**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rookie), especially in a uniformed service. There are alternative phrasings too: *He has taken up stamp collecting. She has trained to be a mailwoman.*

Comment: I am looking for an informal adjective. I think *He has taken up stamp collecting.* would be the closest alternative phrasing. In contrast, "newbie" or "rookie" feel like they've got a slight negative hint to them.

Comment: _Novice_ /'navɪs/ is the traditional name for someone new to an occupation or activity.

Comment: Another frequently used term is _neophyte_. Both _neophyte_ and _novice_ are classed as nouns in many dictionaries (I have just looked up both in Merriam-Webster and Cambridge, just to check, and that is the case there), but I have often heard them used "adjectivally": for example, a _neophyte_ politican or a _novice_ stamp collector.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put people to sleep, you could say *neophyte*.

Better:

- a beginner stamp collector
- a just-starting-out stamp collector
- a recently-hired letter carrier
- a new-hire letter carrier

I wouldn't say *new stamp collector*. That could be someone who collects new stamps.

And *Mailwoman* isn't as common an expression as *letter carrier*—a term invented to correct the sexist (and redundant) *mailman*. (Of course the man's a male. Come on.)

Answer (score 1):

A beginner or novice is a “tyro”.

The Latin root word (also “tyro”) means a new recruit / inexperienced soldier.

Comment: I've never heard of this. Where is it from?

Comment: The Latin word tyro means “recruit”, as in a new recruit / inexperienced soldier.

Comment: Thanks! Could you edit it into your answer?